# Specify base class template parameter depending on the derived class fields

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, crtp

I want to be able to set the type of a data member in a base class to as smaller as possible depending on the number of data members in the derived class. So, if the number of data members in the derived class is 5, type of data member in base class should be `std::uint8_t`.

Here is what I have tried already:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t N>
struct min {
    using type = typename std::conditional_t<
        (N <= 8), std::uint8_t,
        typename std::conditional_t<
            (N <= 16), std::uint16_t,
            typename std::conditional_t<
                (N <= 32), std::uint32_t, std::uint64_t
            >
        >
    >;
};

template <std::size_t N>
using min_t = typename min<N>::type;

template <typename CrtpT, typename T = min_t<CrtpT::end__ - CrtpT::begin__ + 1>>
struct Wrapper {
    T a;
};

struct Foo : Wrapper<Foo> {
    static constexpr int begin__ = __LINE__;
    static constexpr int F_A = 0;
    static constexpr int F_B = 0;
    static constexpr int F_C = 0;
    static constexpr int end__ = __LINE__;
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    std::cout << static_cast<unsigned>(foo.a) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This obviously does not work and does not compile since the `Foo` class is not fully specified at the moment of `Wrapper` class definition.

Does anyone have any better idea on how to do this or is it possible at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated, names like `begin__` are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: It looks like you need reflection. The current solution, even if you get it working, is going to fail if you even add empty lines to `Foo`.

Comment: No offence, but It looks XY problem-ish to me.

Comment: @cigien yes, I am aware of that just hadn't changed it

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I knew someone would tell me that :) ... Here is the small library I am working on at the moment: https://github.com/m-peko/bitflags. I am trying to avoid specifying the data type of each flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround when you need complete type in CRTP is to not use CRTP :), but regular inheritance the other way:

```
template <typename T, typename U = min_t<T::end__ - T::begin__ + 1>>
struct Wrapper : T {
    U a;
};

struct FooImpl {
    static constexpr int begin__ = __LINE__;
    static constexpr int F_A = 0;
    static constexpr int F_B = 0;
    static constexpr int F_C = 0;
    static constexpr int end__ = __LINE__;
};

using Foo = Wrapper<FooImpl>;
```

Comment: Just one side question: Is it somehow possible to set the data type of each `F_A`, `F_B`, etc. to be the one calculated with `min_t`?

Comment: I think you have to rethink your dependencies, Maybe a `template <auto... Vars> struct MyWrapper {/**/};` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the static variables in a separate `Bar` and let `Foo` inherit from that and `Wrapper`.

```
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t N>
struct min {
    using type = typename std::conditional_t<
        (N <= 8), std::uint8_t,
        typename std::conditional_t<
            (N <= 16), std::uint16_t,
            typename std::conditional_t<
                (N <= 32), std::uint32_t, std::uint64_t
            >
        >
    >;
};

template <std::size_t N>
using min_t = typename min<N>::type;

template <typename CrtpT, typename T = min_t<CrtpT::end__ - CrtpT::begin__ + 1>>
struct Wrapper {
    T a = 0;
};

struct Bar {
    static constexpr int begin__ = __LINE__;
    static constexpr int F_A = 0;
    static constexpr int F_B = 0;
    static constexpr int F_C = 0;
    static constexpr int end__ = __LINE__;
};

struct Foo : Bar, Wrapper<Bar> {};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    std::cout << static_cast<unsigned>(foo.a) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit**

To make `F_A`, `F_B` etc the selected type you could make it a template and instatiate it with `int` to get the type.

```
template <typename T>
struct Bar {
    static constexpr int begin__ = __LINE__;
    static constexpr T F_A = 0;
    static constexpr T F_B = 0;
    static constexpr T F_C = 0;
    static constexpr int end__ = __LINE__;
};

struct Foo : Bar<Wrapper<Bar<int>>::type>, Wrapper<Bar<int>> {};
```

Comment: Just one side question: Is it somehow possible to set the data type of each `F_A`, `F_B`, etc. to be the one calculated with `min_t`?

Comment: @NutCracker Added one solution for that. Could be applied to Jarods answer as well.

Comment: thanks. I really learned a lot out of both of these answers. Would give you one more +1 if I could